# How to avoid food spill/stain on bedsheet?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, food, stain

I eat food on my bed. Many times it spills over it and I have to *wash whole bedsheet* just because of this. I usually place some paper or butter paper below it.
[image]

Sometimes it penetrates (oily stuff) through the paper and sometimes the paper is little short to cover things. I don't have big papers or other stuff that can be helpful. Actually I don't know what else can I use and what should I use.

It's curry, rice and chapatis only. I sometimes use plate also, but it also doesn't help.

The spillage isn't a big one, but still it irritates. I have to *think and prepare* myself before eating (like it should not spill), which I guess isn't normal.

I *can't* eat at some other place. I like to eat on bed only.

What I'm currently trying is I guess is just a makeshifter (I mean temporary fix).

Is there any better way to avoid this all experience?

Comment: Hi Vikas, Welcome to Lifehacks. Does the spill penetrate your protection or flow off the edges? Do you have any other place to eat? Do you use plates and dishes? What kinds of foods do you eat that are problematic? Have you figured out how your attempts at spill protection fail in order to modify your next attempt to build/get one to perform better? Please add detail to your question.

Comment: Lifehack: Buy a chair. Sit in that while you eat.

Comment: Btw., don’t take it personal when I disagree with your statement, but IMHO thinking ahead and being prepared for whatever one’s going to do is perfectly normal, even desirable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get a sturdy tray with a rim.

I would recommend a model that can be cleaned easily (e.g. plastic) and is rather sturdy, so that it doesn’t warp or bend when it’s lifted up or set on the bed. That will give you basically a “table without legs”, or a solid surface on which you can place lots of different things that are prone to spilling, rolling away or toppling when placed on a soft surface like a bed. When the inevitable small spillage happens, it won’t hit your bed sheets and you simply have to clean the tray. Bonus: you can still pick up and eat the morsel of food that you dropped on a clean tray.

A tray is also a multitasker - it can corral little things like pens or silverware, be a spot for your cup of morning tea or protect your laptop from overheating.

And when it’s not in use, you can either turn it vertically and slip it in some small slot (e.g. behind your headboard) to make it disappear, yet have it at hand when needed, or display it as decorative item (depending on style and preference). Combined with a small  stool, it could even be a night table next to your bed.

Comment: A "bed tray" is a variation with stubby (short) legs (that may fold for convenience and versatility) that "sits" on your bed top. This tray variation has the added benefit of letting you extend your legs under it while you eat or to support notes, a book, or your computer keyboard when you're not.

Comment: @Stephie can you please add 1-2 images for the same? I don't get the rim thing.

Comment: @Vikas _not_ something like [this](https://www.next.co.uk/g592066s2), because any spillage would simply run off, [this one](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/ostbit-tray-bamboo-30452991/) for example has a solid rim.

Comment: @Vikas you go to [chat].

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53195782#53195782

Answer (score 1):

Although Stephie's answer about the bed tray (or bed table) is probably the best answer, I also want to suggest a very inexpensive lifehack. If you have plastic trash bags, you can lay one out underneath your food before eating. It is much bigger than paper or butter paper, and liquids will not penetrate it. Also, plastic trash bags are very inexpensive, can (probably) be wiped clean if something spills on them, and can be used as an actual trash bag after being used to keep your bed sheets clean.

Comment: Plastic trash bags are not environment friendly?

Comment: @Vikas That is true. However, at least in every apartment building I've lived in, residents are *required* to put their trash in large plastic trash bags before putting them in the dumpster. I suppose a compostable trash bag could be used as a solution for this question, so long as it's still waterproof.

Comment: It's all banned here in India.